Highcharts heatmap is smushing the data and overlapping
I am trying to create a heatmap but the data is getting all smushed and overlapping. Not use what is wrong with my code.


// Substring template helper for the responsive labels
Highcharts.Templating.helpers.substr = (s, from, length) =>
  s.substr(from, length);

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
          backgroundColor: "#fbfcf8",
          type: "heatmap",
          plotBorderWidth: 1,
        },
        title: {
          text: "Views",
          align: "center",
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: true,
          buttons: {
            contextButton: {
              menuItems: [
                "viewFullscreen",
                "printChart",
                "separator",
                "downloadPNG",
                "downloadJPEG",
                "separator",
                "downloadPDF",
                "downloadCSV",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: true,
          itemStyle: {
            color: "#000",
          },
        },
        rangeSelector: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        navigator: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        scrollbar: {
          enabled: false,
        },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      "Africa",
      "North America",
      "South America",
      "Eurasia",
      "Pacifica",
      "South & Central Asia",
      "News Network"
    ]
  },

  yAxis: {
    categories: [
      "Jun 16, 2024",
      "Jun 23, 2024",
      "Jun 30, 2024",
      "Jul 7, 2024",
      "Jul 14, 2024"
    ],
    title: null,
    reversed: true
  },

  accessibility: {
    point: {
      descriptionFormat: '{(add index 1)}. ' +
        '{series.xAxis.categories.(x)} sales ' +
        '{series.yAxis.categories.(y)}, {value}.'
    }
  },

  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    margin: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    symbolHeight: 280
  },

  tooltip: {
    format: '<b>{series.xAxis.categories.(point.x)}</b> sold<br>' +
      '<b>{point.value}</b> items on <br>' +
      '<b>{series.yAxis.categories.(point.y)}</b>'
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Sales per employee',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [
      [0, 0, 1232832],
      [0, 1, 1187983],
      [0, 2, 1318736],
      [0, 3, 3384636],
      [0, 4, 594455],
      [1, 5, 4001117],
      [1, 6, 5292507],
      [1, 7, 6121291],
      [1, 8, 5814796],
      [1, 9, 1611414],
      [2, 10, 208481],
      [2, 11, 218970],
      [2, 12, 225507],
      [2, 13, 600113],
      [2, 14, 191908],
      [3, 15, 2293868],
      [3, 16, 1630162],
      [3, 17, 2099544],
      [3, 18, 1863363],
      [3, 19, 590216],
      [4, 20, 643923],
      [4, 21, 795437],
      [4, 22, 904703],
      [4, 23, 467513],
      [4, 24, 546069],
      [5, 25, 10916105],
      [5, 26, 14178090],
      [5, 27, 12766301],
      [5, 28, 21131347],
      [5, 29, 5413607],
      [6, 30, 206725],
      [6, 31, 231642],
      [6, 32, 238180],
      [6, 33, 319477],
      [6, 34, 133786]
    ],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#000000'
    }
  }],

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        yAxis: {
          labels: {
            format: '{substr value 0 1}'
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }

});
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>



I have also attached a fiddle. Please let me know how to fix this.

There's not enough place for the dataLabels to be rendered. I suggest limiting the yAxis range so the points become bigger or displaying only some of the dataLabels. Example demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bwLvoud6/
